# Elasticsearch : Error: Could not find or load main class Warning

Tags: elasticsearch, service, elk

i installed ELK7 one week ago , it was working fine today i got this error saying

**Could not find or load main class Warning**

[image]

here is Environement variables:

[image]

**important Note**

i found that Elasticsearch service stops alone after running it

**what i tried :**

- check if any environment variable do not have the correct path.
- reinstall Elasticsearch again.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, I upgrade JAVA to the latest (17) and this resolved the issue